# Flexbox: How to Combine percent, pixels and remaining height on columns?

Tags: css, height, flexbox, stretch

I'm building basic grid system and need to combine height of flex-items described in different size units, which are %, px and remaining space.

html:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block" style="flex-basis: 50px;">50px</div>
  <div class="block" style="flex-basis: 25%;">25%</div>
  <div class="block">stretch to remaining space?</div>
  <div class="block" style="flex-basis: 50px;">50px</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,body,.grid {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}
.block {
  outline: solid 1px black;
  flex-grow: 0; // remove growing proportion
  flex-shrink: 0; // remove shrinking proportion
}
```

working example:
http://codepen.io/antraxis/pen/zxwgEo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `flex-grow` parameter (the first one in the `flex` shorthand property) :

HTML :

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block a">block height 50px</div>
  <div class="block b">block height 25%</div>
  <div class="block c">block height *</div>
  <div class="block d">block height 50px</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.block {
  outline: solid 1px black;
}
.a, .d {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.b {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.c {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawBzJ)

Comment: that's exactly what I tried too... setting grow for only one element. I'm not sure if that's a proper way to do it, but does it's job.

Comment: Of course it's the proper way : you say that 3 elements doesn't grow (0) and that one should grow (1).